# How to find indices of a given value in python multi list?

Tags: python

Given below is a sample multi list, that I am working with. Now I need to  find the `indices` of a given value if it appears anywhere in the list. For eg: for `lis[0][2][2][1][0] which is 'span 1 2'`, I would like to get the index as `[0,2,2,1,0]`.

```
lis = [['Root', ['span 1 6'], ['Nucleus', ['span 1 3'], ['Nucleus', ['span 1 2'],  ['Nucleus', ['leaf 1'],  ['text',  "Specific knowledge "]], ['Satellite', ['leaf 2'], ['rel2par Elaboration'], ['text', 'required !_']]], ['Satellite', ['leaf 3'], ['rel2par Elaboration'], ['text', 'The tester is ']]], ['Satellite', ['span 4 6'], ['rel2par Elaboration'], ['Satellite', ['leaf 4'], ['rel2par Attribution'], ['text', 'For instance , the tester is aware!_']], ['Nucleus', ['span 5 6'],  ['Nucleus', ['leaf 5'], ['rel2par Contrast'], ['text', 'that a!_']], ['Nucleus', ['leaf 6'], ['rel2par Contrast'], ['text', 'but ']]]]]]
```

I tried the following (modified from a web source).

```
from copy import copy
def scope2(word, list, indexes = None):
    flag = 0
    result = []
    if not indexes:
        indexes = []
    for index, item in enumerate(list):
        try:
            current_index = indexes + [index]
            result.append(current_index + [item.index(word)])
        except ValueError:
            pass
        print item
        print str(current_index) + ":::::" + str(list.index(item))
        for stuff in item:        
            if type(stuff) == type([]):
                flag =1 

    if flag==1:
        indexes.append(index)
        result.extend(scope2(word, item, copy(indexes)))

return result
```

Here the problem is that the index of sibling (lists at same level) also gets returned, but not always. Some sample outputs are like

`for 0,2,3,1 it returns 0,2,3,1,0, similarly for lis[0][2][3][4][3][3] it returns  0,2,3,3,4,3,3` and so on. What can be the possible problem?

Comment: `lis[0][2][3][1]` is `['leaf 3']`. `lis[0][2][2][1][0]` is `'span 1 2'`.

Comment: @falsetru sorry, it is lis[0][2][2][1][0] only. edited in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> def trail(word, lst):
...     if word in lst:
...         return [lst.index(word)]
...     for i, x in enumerate(lst):
...         if not isinstance(x, list):
...             continue
...         ret = trail(word, x)
...         if ret is not None:
...             return [i] + ret
... 
>>> trail('span 1 2', lis)
[0, 2, 2, 1, 0]
>>> lis[0][2][2][1][0]
'span 1 2'
>>> trail('no such string', lis)
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation of depth first and breadth first searching, not limited to strings. Would require a little reworking to search for a list or a tuple.

```
>>> l = [['Root', ['span 1 6'], ['Nucleus', ['span 1 3'], ['Nucleus', ['span 1 2'],  ['Nucleus', ['leaf 1'],  ['text',  "Specific knowledge "]], ['Satellite', ['leaf 2'], ['rel2par Elaboration'], ['text', 'required !_']]], ['Satellite', ['leaf 3'], ['rel2par Elaboration'], ['text', 'The tester is ']]], ['Satellite', ['span 4 6'], ['rel2par Elaboration'], ['Satellite', ['leaf 4'], ['rel2par Attribution'], ['text', 'For instance , the tester is aware!_']], ['Nucleus', ['span 5 6'],  ['Nucleus', ['leaf 5'], ['rel2par Contrast'], ['text', 'that a!_']], ['Nucleus', ['leaf 6'], ['rel2par Contrast'], ['text', 'but ']]]]]]
>>> def depth_first(term,data):
...   for i, item in enumerate(data):
...     if isinstance(item,Sequence) and not isinstance(item,basestring):
...       r = depth_first(term,item)
...       if not r is None:
...         return [i] + r
...     else:
...       if item == term:
...         return [i]
...
>>> def breadth_first(term,data):
...   later = []
...   for i, item in enumerate(data):
...     if isinstance(item,Sequence) and not isinstance(item,basestring):
...       later.append((i,item))
...     else:
...       if item == term:
...         return [i]
...   for i, item in later:
...     r = breadth_first(term,item)
...     if not r is None:
...       return [i] + r
>>> depth_first('span 1 2',l)
[0, 2, 2, 1, 0]
>>> breadth_first('span 1 2',l)
[0, 2, 2, 1, 0]
```